# if array undefined

Tags: php

How do I check if an array is undefined?
I am using `isset` and `empty` but both of them are not working for an undefined array.

This is my code:

```
if (isset($content['menu']['main'])){
    echo 'there is menu';               
}
```

Comment: You mean [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your example. What exactly do you mean by `not working`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this code as specified by **Rikesh** and **mimipc**

```
$arr = array("menu"=>array("main"=>1));
if (is_array($arr) && array_key_exists('menu', $arr)) {
     echo "array";
}
```

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/Q3gTwn

Answer (score 3):

Based on your code, I think you're looking for the function [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/function.array-key-exists.php).

```
$content = array('menu'=>array());
echo isset($content);
>>> 1
echo array_key_exists('menu', $content);
>>> 1
if ( array_key_exists('main', $content['menu']) ) {
    echo "Main menu exists";
} else {
    echo "Main menu does not exist";
}
>>> Main menu does not exist
```

`isset()` will not work, because the variable `$content` is set, and the array may not be empty, so `empty()` will also not work. You want to see if the `main` key exists in the `$content['menu']` array.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if an array element exists with `in_array`:

```
in_array('one', array('two', 'three', 'four')); // false
```

And you can check array-indexes with `array_key_exists`:

```
array_key_exists('metallica', array('metallica' => 'worst than megadeth')); // true
```

With the `isset` function you only check if the array or variable is not equal to `NULL` and if it contains a value which can be interpreted as boolean `True` or `False`, integers larger than `0` and if the variable value (or array key/index/element) is not equal to `NULL`.

I usualy check if variable is set with: `is_null`, and it can be used to check if an array index or an element is defined within that same array.

EDIT:

You can also check if a variable is array with: `(sizeof($something) > 0)` or with: `is_array` function(s).